# How to change the cart button links on menu?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, menu, cart, storefront

I want to change the links of cart button on the menu.

For now I activated "WooCommerce Menu Cart" plugin and using storefront theme.

I googled and tried this one.

```
/**
 * Set a custom add to cart URL to redirect to
 * @return string
 */
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
    return 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your-page/'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

But this work for only "view cart" buttons on pages.

What I want is to change the menu cart link url to something like this.

From

```
http://mydomain.name/cart
```

To

```
http://mydomain.name/custom_cart_page
```

Comment: You can change woocommerce settings > checkout *(tab)* > 
Cart page *(line)*

Answer (score 0):

If it only changes the url on the same domain, you just need to edit (the cart page) then change the slug.